# USB car charger input 10vdc instead of 12 VDC

Tags: usb, charger, automotive

I am running a project where I will have a small steam engine turning a dynamo. the dynamo produces 12VDC no load and 10VDC 10 watts under load.
My plan was to buy a car usb charger and connect it up as a fun experiment with my son as an alternative way to charge his iPhone and learn about the industrial revolution.
Trouble is how will a car charger cope with 10VDC instead of 12VDC input?

Thats my question and thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it will be fine.  Without any more details, however, there is no way to definatively answer the question.  The best way to get the answer is to look at the datasheet of the charger to see what its input voltage requirements are.